# How to set/use Custom Validator syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good Morning

I have studying C# and .net recently and try to make registration page.

IF Username = 'HelloWorld1' and Password ='Password'

Basically I try to test that if users are admin or employees which I hardcode in database already,

then this test box will show up

then

```
<!--this is html code -->
<tbody id ="tbody" runat="server" visible ="false">
            <tr>





                <td class="auto-style1">IsEmployee</td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">


                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>IsAdmin</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
```

shows up

my code is

```
 protected void CustomValidator3_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {

            String Artists = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FleetManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Artists);

            SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.UserLoggins where UserName ='HelloWorld1' and Password ='password'", con);
            SqlDataReader objReader;
            con.Open();
            objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (objReader.HasRows)
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
                tbody.Visible = true;

                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

How can I make this code work?

Thank you so much, Have a great day.

Comment: Why not use the Asp.Net Membership Provider? As is, you have in line SQL which is vulnerable to SQL injection, you have hard coded usernames and passwords _in your code_, and you're obviously storing your passwords as plaintext rather than hashing them. This is a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will google for  Asp.Net Membership Provider. Step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, there are issues, but if you are just trying to get your example working try this. Assuming you custom validator control is properly configured you just want to return whether IsValid is true or false.

```
int count = 0;

using (SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FleetManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) from dbo.UserLoggins where UserName =@User and Password =@Password", con);

    SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) { Value = "HelloWorld1" };
    command.Parameters.Add(paramName);

    SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) { Value = "password" };
    command.Parameters.Add(paramName);

    con.Open();
    count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

}

args.IsValid = count > 0;
return;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i am learning a lot of stuffs. I really appreciate the help!!!!!!